# Failed to get the values of $_POST super global array inside a function in WordPress plugin creation

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, post

I am new to wordpress and i am trying to create a simple plugin that inserts and fetches data into mysql database. The problem comes when i want to access the super global `$_POST` array  inside my `PHP function`. I can see the values being passed through `$_POST` array if i use `print_r($_POST)` function outside my `PHP function`. But if i try to use `print_r($_POST)` inside my function, it displays nothing.

I am using `jQuery Post AJAX` request to submit the form.

I want to access `$_POST` array inside my `PHP function` query mysql to fetch data from the database and return the results from the function where required.

My Plugin's directory structure looks like this.

```
auc_result_fetcher //this is the main plugin folder

    auc_result_fetcher.php // This file includes other scripts using include function
    includes // directory containing other files to be included

         fetch.php   // this file contains the functions to fetch data from mysql db 
         scripts.php // this file contains the enqueue code of js and css scripts  
         search.php  // this file contains form to submit data and also displays it 

         js //directory contsins js files

            auc-custom-jquery.js 

         css //directory contsins css files

            auc-custom-stylesheet.css
```

**auc_result_fetcher.php contains this code**

```
/*plugin header information goes here..*/

/************
AUC Constants
*************/

define("PAGE_URI", plugins_url());
define("SEARCH_RESULTS", PAGE_URI."/auc_result_fetcher/includes/fetch.php/");

/************
AUC Includes
*************/
include ("includes/scripts.php");
include ("includes/fetch.php");
include ("includes/search.php");
```

**search.php contains this code**

```
add_action('init', function() {
   add_shortcode('search_form', 'print_search_form');
});
add_action('init', 'fetch_grades');
add_action('init', 'fetch_search_options');
add_action('init', 'fetch_student_results');


function print_search_form(){
?>
<div class="auc-search-form">
    <div id="error">

        <div id="select-class-error"></div>
        <div id="select-search-by-error"></div>
        <div id="search-field-error"></div>

    </div>
    <form id="searchForm" method="get" action="">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:right;"> <span>Class:</span> </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="select-class">
                        <option>Select Class</option>
                        <?php

                        $grades = fetch_grades();
                        foreach($grades AS $v){
                            echo "<option>".$v->grade_title."</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td id="class-select"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="previous-row">
                <td style="text-align:right;"> <span>Search By:</span> </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="search-by">
                        <option>Select Choice</option>
                        <?php

                        $grades = fetch_search_options();
                        foreach($grades AS $v){
                            echo "<option>".$v->search_title."</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr id="search-row">
                <td id="search-by-option-label" style="text-align:right;"><span></span></td>
                <td id="search-by-field"><input type="text" name="searchBy" id="search" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr >
                <td ></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" id="url" name="url" value="<?php echo SEARCH_RESULTS; ?>">
                    <input type="button"  id="search-button" value="Search" />
                    <input type="reset" name="searchBy" id="reset" value="Cancel"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <table id="results-table">
        <tr>
            <th>Roll Number</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>School</th>
            <th>Class</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        fetch_student_results();
        /*echo "<pre>";
        print_r($d);
        echo "</pre>";*/    
        ?>
    </table>
</div>
<?php
}
```

**fetch.php contains this code**

```
<?php 

// fetches student's grades for example: 9th, 10th grade
function fetch_grades(){
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp-student-grade`");
if($result){
     return $result;
}
return false;
}

// fetches student's grades search options for example: by name, by roll number, by school
function fetch_search_options(){
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp-grade_search_options`");
if($result){
     return $result;
}
return false;
}

//
function fetch_student_results(){
  if(!empty($_POST))
   print_r($_POST);
}
```

**auc-custom-jquery.js contains this code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

       var selectCls = $("select#select-class").val();
       var searchBy = $("select#search-by").val();
       var searchField = $("input#search").val();
   var url = $("input#url").val(); 

       $.post(url, {c: selectCls, s: searchBy, f: searchField}, function(data){

    alert(data);

   });

});
```

EDIT: Please have a look on my detailed code so that you can understand what is going on.

Please help me out how can i achieve this. This behavior seems wordpress specific. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have posted my code. Please have a look.

Comment: ajax call, debug this using apache's error log,i would have used error_log(print_r($_POST,true));

Comment: i also used `error_log(print_r($_POST,true));` and it also does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, read the Q a bit to fast.

Ok, so you are submitting the form to e.g. `myfile.php`.

Inside `myfile.php` you are able to do print_r($_POST). If yes then:

```
$data = $_POST;

$result = do_something($data);


function do_something($data){
  // Do something with the $data and return result
}
```

Comment: @Rebbeca want to access posted data of form using ajax not the $post wordpress data post data.